# Denote $X = {1, 2,..., 100}$. $B$ is a $8$-element subset of $X$

Tags: combinatorics

Denote $X = \{1, 2,..., 100\}$. $B$ is a $8$-element subset of $X$. Prove that there are two subsets of $B$ such that sum of all elements are equal. Is there a simple way?

Comment: Try constructing two subsets which have this property. Then suppose there is another, and show it is equal to one of the two you already have.

Comment: What makes you think this is true? It is trivial for a 10-element subset (pigeonhole principle), true but hard to prove for a 9-element subset. Oh, and obviously false for a 7-element subset (take the elements as distinct powers of 2).

Comment: The result is false, but I suspect that it is true for $9$ elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is false.

Try the subset $\{1,2,12,24,48,92,96,100\}$.

Mathematica: DuplicateFreeQ[Map[Total[Subsets[{1, 2, 12, 24, 48, 92, 96, 100}]]]] gives True.

Answer (score 0):

The result is false: a counterexample is
$$\{ 1, 6,12,24,48,94,96,98 \}$$
(checked with a computer).